# Xpath and regex for autocompletion filter

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xmldocument

I have got a huge xml document.

something like that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<elements>
 <element id="1" name="france" />
 <element id="2" name="usa" />
 <element id="3" name="Spaïn" />
 <element id="4" name="spain and africa" />
 <element id="5" name="italie and Spâin" />
</elements>
```

I want to have something like this :

```
string str = "spain";
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();                
xmlDoc.LoadXml(myXML);
// Xpath with regex or something very veloce
XmlNodeList xmlNodeList =  xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//element"+ something);
```

And the xmlNodeList will contains :

```
<element id="3" name="Spaïn" />
<element id="4" name="france with spâin and africa" />
<element id="5" name="italie and Spain" />
```

**it must ignore the case**
**And accent**

for the moment I've

```
XmlNodeList xmlNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/*/*[contains(concat(' ',translate(translate(@n,translate(@n, 'aaabcdefghiiijklmnopqrstuvwxyzâÂABCDEFGHïÏIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', ''),''), 'âÂABCDEFGHïÏIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','aaabcdefghiiijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),' '),' "+prefix+" ')]");
```

where @n = @name and prefix is maybe : "spain" or "Spain" or "Spaïn" and it give me 0 solution

Comment: if your filter is something that the user provides then be sure to escape it somehow. If for example the user enters some string  containing xpath special characters then `SelectNodes` may throw

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a more general solution that allows any non-alphabetic characters to delimit any word. :)

Comment: @Christophe-Debove: Thank you for making this problem even more interesting. See my updated answer. :)

Comment: @Christophe-Debove: I have made an exhaustive search and it appears that my solution is probably the only way to solve your problem. In particular, there *isn't* a way to specify in a RegEx a character class for "all accented characters for A" or for any single, specific character. This means that even using a Regex, all accent characters must be enumerated. Thus, one would not gain anything better than my solution, if he decides to write a RegEx instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**:
As the original problem was changed adding the requirement to recognize the word "Spain" not only in all possible capitalizations but also including accented characters, I have updated the solution below so that now "Spain" with **âÂ** and/or **ïÏ** is correctly recognized.

**Here is a more generic solution than that of @Alejandro**:

If we want to select all elements, whose `name` attribute contains the word "Spain" in any capitalization and if the possible word delimiters are all non-alphabetic characters, then

**This XPath expression**:

```
/*/*[contains(
              concat(' ',
                     translate(translate(@name,
                                         translate(@name, $vAlpha, ''),
                                         '                                                           '),
                               $vUpper,
                               $vLower),
                     ' '
                     ),
              ' spain '
              )
     ]
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<elements>
 <element id="1" name="france" />
 <element id="2" name="usa" />
 <element id="3" name="Spaïn" />
 <element id="4" name="france with spâin and africa" />
 <element id="5" name="-Spain!" />
 <element id="6" name="spain and africa" />
 <element id="7" name="italie and Spain." />
</elements>
```

**selects the following elements**:

```
<element id="3" name="Spaïn"/>
<element id="4" name="france with spâin and africa"/>
<element id="5" name="-Spain!"/>
<element id="6" name="spain and africa"/>
<element id="7" name="italie and Spain."/>
```

In the above XPath expression `$vLower`, `$vUpper` must be substituted with (respectively):

```
'aaabcdefghiiijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

and

```
'âÂABCDEFGHïÏIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

`$vAlpha` must be substituted by the concatenation of `$vLower` and `$vUpper` .

Comment: +1 Yes, this is a good solution also, adding the requeriment of removing punctuation

Comment: @Christophe-Debove: Thank you for making this problem even more interesting. See my updated answer. :)

Comment: @Dimitre it could work but I'm looking for something more automatic, with your way we cannot avoid to miss some õ è ù or trival(non-latin) caracter

Comment: @Christophe-Debove: Not only "it could work", but it works! As for using this as "automatic" solution -- yes, simply add to the `$vLower` and `$vUpper` variables all accented characters in the manner demonstrated in my solution -- there are just a few vowels and each of them has only a few accented variations. Do you mind an XPath 2.0 solution (it might be necessary for you to access a non-standard XPath (2.0) engine, such as Saxon or XQSharp)?

Comment: @Dimitre maybe it's me but I don't arrive to make it work I edit my question to add my C# code

Comment: @Christophe-Debove: My code is always tested before I publish it. In your latest edit the XPath expression you use refers to a `@n` attribute and no such attribute exists in your XML document. Thus no node is selected. Use just the document and XPath expression from my answer and you can easily verify that exactly the wanted elements are selected.

Comment: @Christophe-Debove: If your problems verifying the solution persist, you can contact me using my wordpress blog userid as userid on the google mail. This may save a lot of iterations/time.

Comment: @Dimitre ok I managed, the problem is fix Thank you a lot for helping me

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
//element[contains(concat(' ',translate(@name,'SPAIN','spain'),' '),' spain ')]
```

**Edit**: Now, the question has changed, but the answer remains...

Just add these changes in the translation pattern like:

```
//element[contains(concat(' ',
                          translate(@name,
                                    'SPAÂâIÏïN',
                                    'spaaaiiin'),
                          ' '),
                   ' spain ')]
```

**Note:** Of course, a more general expression would need a more general translation pattern.

Comment: yo Alejandro could you explain the use of adding concat?

Comment: @Treemonkey: Yes. `contains(@name,'spain')` would match "spainly".

Comment: would it still get the element if the name was just name="spain" as there is no spaces? thanks for reply :)

Comment: @Treemonkey: Yes, because the concatenation of leading and trailing space to `@name`.

Comment: Can you remove the // of your answer in order it has syntax color

Comment: @Christophe Debove: Google prettifier doesn't handle XPath anyway.

Comment: @Alejandro: Perhaps my answer would be interesting to you.

Answer (score 2):

```
string str = "spain";
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();                
xmlDoc.LoadXml(myXML);
// Xpath with regex or something very veloce
XmlNodeList xmlNodeList =  xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//element[contains(@name,'spain')]");
```